# object reference not set to an instance

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new to c# and web services... Normally i use python for a long time...

I need to wirete a web service that will be run on IIS, local debugging was successful, i deploy it to my local test server but since that is ona another computer, i could not test it completely via a web browser...

When i try to access it iwth suds (python), my first test function `Hello World` runs correctly, that shows me my serice is accessible...

but when i try to call a service funton that accepts a parameter and return a custon defined data type, my service simply returns `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

As i said, i am new to c# and web services... So i could not spot my mistake :(

```
public class Balance{
    private decimal _currentBalance;
    public decimal currentBalance
    {
        get { return _currentBalance; }
        set { _currentBalance = value; }
    }
}



public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private string _deviceId;

    public string deviceId
    {
        get { return _deviceId; }
        set { _deviceId = value; }
    }
    CrAc conn;
    CResult connResult;

    private void connectToServer()
    {
        conn= new CrAc();
        connResult= conn.Connect(deviceId);
    }

    private bool connectionControl()
    {
        return connResult.CRCStatus;
    }

    [WebMethod(Description="asdf")]
    public Balance checkBalance(string deviceId) {
        Balance balance = new balance {currentBalance= 0.00m};
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        connectToServer();
        if (connectionControl())
        {
            XResult askBalance = conn.someFunc(deviceId);
            balance.currentBalance = askBalance.availableBalance;
        }
     return balance;
    }
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: .net exceptions contain a lot more information than just that; they contain a stacktrace, and usually the line number. That *alone* should lead you exactly to the misbehaving code.

Comment: in which line you get the error?

Comment: Your web service method doesn't appear to have a return statement so I wouldn't think this would even compile!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we solve the problem...

I was using a DLL that i got from api provider, which has some control function for cpu and network device id's. My development machine was a win7, but on the test server, we have virtual win7 that runs on virtual box... Since virtual Operating systems do not have real cpu or network IDs', api DLL fails on a virtual operating system,but runs perfectly on a real machine...

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to be certain based on the given information, but my bet is that `baglanti.someFunc(deviceId)` returns `null`, and that you get an exception when trying to get  `bakiyeSorgusu.availableBalance`. If so, I would:

- Examine under what circumstances `someFunc` may return `null` and decide whether that is ok or not.
- If it is OK, add a null check in your service call, so that you don't try to get `availableBalance` from null references
- If it's not OK, fix the bug in `someFunc`.

<sub>As a side note, I would recommend you to write code in English if possible (at least when posting code samples online). That way the code will make sense to a lot more people.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your method bakiyeSor isn't return a value. A `return` is missing.

Comment: Sorry, fixed... My code is much more longer, so this is the part i had problem...